# Enable Typescript compiler on empty ASP.Net 5 preview template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new project based on the ASP.Net 5 Preview Web Site template, I can edit my TypeScript files and they are compiled automatically, and the compiled JS file is displayed in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

However, when I select the empty template, my TypeScript files aren't compiling:

[image]

How do I set up TypeScript compilation like in the regular project template?